# How Can I find the min and max values of y and draw a border between them in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, graph

I am currently gathering `X gyro data` of a device. I need to find the differences between them in terms of their `y values` in the graphs [such as this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZysbK.png)

I have written an algorithm where it finds the min and max y value but when they have some minor fluctuations like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhHaq.png) my algorithm returns faulty answers. I have written it in python and it is as follows;

```
import numpy as np

x, y = np.loadtxt("gyroDataX.txt", unpack=True, delimiter=",")

max_value = max(y)
min_value = min(x)
print(min_value)

borders = max_value - min_value
```

I need to now write and algorithm that will;

- Determine the max and min y value and draw their borders.
- If it sees minor fluctuations it will ignore them.

Would writing such an algorithm be possible, and if so how could I go about writing one? Is there any libraries or any reading material you would recommend? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Generally maths like this should be done in pure code, with the help of little or none external API's, so it's easier to debug the algorithm and processes.

**2.** Now for a possible answer:

Since you do not want any **outliers** (those buggy and irritating minor fluctuations), you need to calculate the `standard deviation` of your data.

**What is the standard deviation, you might ask?**
It represents how far your data is from the `mean`(Symbol: µ) (average) of your data set.

If you do not know what it is, here is [quick tutorial](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html) on the standard deviation and its partner, variance.

**First, the `MEAN`**:

It should not be that hard to calculate the `mean` of your `x` and `y` arrays/lists . Just loop (`for loop` would be optimal) through the lists and add up all the values and divide it by the length of the list itself. There you have the `mean`.

**Second, the `VARIANCE`(σ squared)**:

**If you followed the website above**, to calculate the `variance`, loop through the `x` and `y` lists again, subtract the x and y values from their respective `mean` to get the difference, square this difference, add all the differences up and divide by the length of the respective lists and you have the `variance`.

For the `Standard Deviation` (Symbol: σ), just take the square root of the `variance`.

Now the standard deviation can be used to find the real max and min (leaving out those buggy outliers).
Use this graph as an **approximate** reference to find where your most of your values may be:

[image]

Since your data is mostly uniform, you should get a pretty accurate answer.
Do test the different situations: `σ + µ` or `2σ + µ`; to find the optimum max and min.

**Edit:**

Sorry, only `y` now:

[image]

Sorry for the horrible representation and drawing. **This is what it should like graphically is**. Also do experiment by yourself with the `Standard Deviation` from the `mean` (like above; `σ + µ` or `2σ + µ`) to find the your suited max and min.

Comment: I don't understand the last note. Variable `x` appears to represent measurement points; from the pictures it looks like `x` should be expected to have the same distribution in both situations. It's mostly the standard deviation of `y` that we're interested in. If the distributions of `x` do differ, then I think the best thing to do is to resample so that the `x` no longer differ, then calculate the standard deviation of `y`.

Comment: Oh, you are only looking for `y` values, then just forget the `x` and only calculate for the `y` (Ignore the last note).  _"If the distributions of `x` do differ, then I think the best thing to do is to resample so that the `x` no longer differ"_ : You do not need to sort the `x` anymore, cause the `y` values are independent of `x`. Therefore, the outliers you want to remove in the `y` are also independent of `x`. Basically,  `x` does not affect `y` and since you are only dealing with one data set (`y`, if i have not made it clear) the **mean and standard deviation** method is applicable here.

Comment: Also, I will edit the question for clarity!